# How to remove all files containing not recognized characters in bash?

Tags: bash

I recovered a drive on which a wrong rm command was fired. Now I have a folder containing a million text files named progressively as 00000001.txt 00000002.txt ...
A lot of them contain just unrecognized characters as yÏÞxìÏ¾ûïgçØ>o|ø>*ß>Ï3ìó} .. 
How could I  easily remove the files containing there characters using bash?

Comment: What exactly does it mean to be "unrecognized" characters? You're going to have to clarify. Do you expect the contents to be entirely ASCII?

Comment: @Borealid The files I might want to keep are those created by the users on a normal routine .. so they just open a text-editor and save their files .. I think ascii utf8 and iso-8859-1 could be the reference codes. The files I want to remove are those with a non readable content if opened with a normal editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *.txt
do
    if ! chardet "$i" | grep -q 'ascii'
    then
        echo rm "$i"
    fi
done
```

Comment: sorry .. maybe I wrote my question badly. The unrecognized characters are in the file content not in the file name :)

Comment: I've updated. You can use the `chardet` command to check the encoding of a file. If not `ascii`, delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally what honeyp0t said, but if that doesn't work, there is another way using the system tool `clri`, which is usually called "strong medicine".

What `clri` does is deleting an inode directly off the filsystem. You need to know the file's inode number. Here's the idea:

1. You use `ls -il` to list the files, where the inode number is the number leftmost in the output.
2. Repeat 1) for all bad files and then unmount the filesystem.
3. Run `clri` *inode-number* for the bad files.
4. Run fsck and let it repair the damage.

Good luck.

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
 22005 drwxrwxr-x  2 bos  bos       2504 Apr 13  2011 scripts
```

22005 is the inode number for the directory "scripts" on my system.

Comment: GNU find can delete based on an inode too. `find . -maxdepth 1 -inum <inode> -delete`

Answer (score 0):

```
egrep "[^a-Z ,.;:#+*?-9°$'\"<=>|_\!-]" {00000001..1000000}.txt
```

should be a start, to show, which other characters to include.

With

```
 egrep -q FILE && rm FILE
```

you can delete everything, which does match your pattern:

```
 for f in {00000001..1000000}.txt
 do
     egrep -q "[^a-Z ,.:#+*?-9°$'\"<=>|_\!-]" "$f" && rm "$f"
 done
```

There is surely some optimization possible for the regex.